# Laravel, using popup alerts

Tags: laravel

I have a question. What I want is to show two popup alerts during redirection.

what i do is this :

```
  return redirect()->back()->with('success', sprintf('Image was successfully updated.'))->with('info', sprintf('Please confirm your email.'));
```

What is see is that the second message overwrites the first one. So when it redirects I can see only the second one.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: How are you showing these popup alerts?

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/View/View.html#method_with

```
  return redirect()->back()->with(
['success' => sprintf('Image was successfully updated.'),
'info' => sprintf('Please confirm your email.')]);
```

Why are you using `sprintf` with no formatting of the string? You may as well take it out.